# How to open new cmd window and execute for-loop in it?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a test.cmd file with the following command:

```
call "cmd /c start echo foo && pause"
call "cmd /c start for /l %%x in (0, 1, 2) do python test.py config%%x"
```

The first command is working fine and shows that the general approach should work. The second one with the for loop gives me troubles.

When I run this command directly in a CMD window (with only one % sign before the iterator), it starts my python script "test.py" in a new CMD window 3 times in a loop as expected.

When I run the same command from my test.cmd (this time with two % of course), the new CMD window pops up and is gone right away. I don't get any error messages and can't get the new window to stay.

I suspect that I need to do some more encoding but I cannot figure out the correct syntax. What must I change to get this for loop to run from my test.cmd?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you insist on using `call`, there is another level of parsing, so in a batchfile you have to use:

```
call "cmd /k start for /l %%%%i in (1,1,10) do echo %%%%i"
```

(replaced `/c` with `/k` to see the output)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
call "cmd /c for /l %x in (0, 1, 2) do @python test.py config%x"
```

when you execute loops in command prompt you need single percentage symbol.
And you need to remove the start command after the `cmd /c` because `for` is internal cmd command. The `@` is for suppress printing of prompt value on each iteration.

Comment: Your solution works from the cmd-line, but fails when I start it via my test.cmd. I get the following error message.

C:\>call "cmd /c for /l x"
x" was unexpected at this time.

Comment: @Demento Why do you not simply use in your `test.cmd` the line `for /L %%x in (0,1,2) do python.exe test.py config%%x` as this makes more sense to me?

Comment: @Demento - to use this from batch script you need to double the percent symbols.

Comment: @Mofi I need the "call" because I want to run several of those for loops in parallel in different cmd windows. I omitted the other loops to keep the example simple.

Answer (score 1):

This answer elaborates on the core question stated in the title of your post rather than on the sample code you provided.

---

To run a `for` loop in a separate (`cmd`) window, the `start` command is needed. In addition, An explicit `cmd` instance should be given in order to avoid problems with `start` when calling internal command lines (for instance, parentheses may cause errors), and also to have control over what happens with the new window after the loop has finished.

The following command line runs a `for` loop in a new `cmd` window, which remains open after the loop finished (quite helpful for debugging):

```
start "" /WAIT cmd /K "for /L %%X in (0,1,2) do echo %%X"
```

Type `exit` into the new window to close it. To automatically close the new window finally, replace `/K` by `/C`.

If you do not want your main (calling) batch script to wait for the loop to finish and the new window to be closed, remove the `/WAIT` switch. This way the command line is started, but the main script immediately continues executing. This allows you to run multiple `for` loops in separate windows simultaneously.

---

This technique is not limited to calling `for` loops only.